# Is there any way I can get my Google Chrome to go back a page by pressing backspace?

Tags: browser, google-chrome

Something I seem to be missing is when I press backspace the page doesn't go back to the last page as it did in Windows, does anyone have any ways around this?

Answer (score 10):

Workaround:

<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

Answer (score 9):

There is a [Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aeffggjddcchloadflonilaahpclmbnm) to do this. Once installed you need to enable it in its options.

Comment: Please note that the extension requires quite extensive permissions. Clearly, since it has to navigate your history. A little paranoia has never hurt anyone :)

Advice to use arrow-workaround ALT+(Left|Right)Arrow

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if there is a possibility to do that.
But I have a workaround which works with every browsers on every platforms: you can use Alt+Left-Arrow to go back. Many applications that offers "navigation" have this shortcut also, so it is a worthy investment to try learning it :)
So:
Alt+Left-Arrow to go back
Alt+Right-Arrow to go forward
Very useful :)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't included by default in Chrome on Linux since this (as I have read somewhere) is "not the Linux way" of navigating. <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> can be used for navigating through history.

Comment: I hate all this decisions like the disabling of "one click selects all" in the url bar