# How to make backspace work in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

My girl friend has just switched to Ubuntu on her laptop (Yay!), but she complains about backspace not going back in history in Google Chrome.

I know that in Firefox you can change the behaviour([Pressing backspace doesn't open previous page in Firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28284/pressing-backspace-doesnt-open-previous-page-in-firefox)), but she uses Chrome (!). Is there something that can be done to restore the behaviour to Chrome?

Comment: Is this true for every website? Because backspace can be blocked by javascripts.

Comment: Yes it is. Does it work for you?

Comment: `Alt + left` and `Alt + right` are shortcuts for back/forward in chrome on Linux.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:**

[With the update to 35.0 backspace now works again by default in Chrome/Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30699#c67).

---

**Original post**:

Looks as if there is an extension for this available on the Chrome Webstore:

[Backspace As Back/Forward for Linux](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backspace-as-backforward/aeffggjddcchloadflonilaahpclmbnm)

Comment: Will test it as soon as I get home :)

Comment: The [reviews](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/backspace-as-backforward/aeffggjddcchloadflonilaahpclmbnm/reviews?hl=en) on the extension are mixed.

Comment: I have tried this and it is now working(+1). **Another thing to think of is device drivers are not available for some boxes in ubuntu or *nix environments. When I used this same box with windows 7, it worked well as it had all drivers loaded**.

Comment: Works in 90% of the cases, but behaves really poor when trying to delete characters from an input inside a Flash app (takes you back).

Comment: Does anyone know a way to do the opposite of this? remove this "feature" that was added in chrome 35.0?